# Splitting Order is not working in magento

Tags: php, magento

This code is not completely splitting my order. Still subtotal and grand total of bill is not split up. This code is splitting order's product fine. Is there any other code that is working well with this. I want to split order on the bases of supplier. The products from one supplier should be in one order and the other one's should be in other. Please suggest me some useful links.

Below is my code. This is an observer of order save.

```
<?php

class Custom_SplitOrderObserver_Model_Checkout_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage {

    /**
     * Create order based on checkout type. Create customer if necessary.
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage

 */
public function saveOrder() {
    $this->validate();
    $isNewCustomer = false;
    switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
        case self::METHOD_GUEST:
            $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
            break;
        case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
            $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
            $isNewCustomer = true;
            break;
        default:
            $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
            break;
    }

    $cart = $this->getQuote();
    $key = 0;

    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $key = $key + 1;
        $temparray[$key]['product_id'] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $temparray[$key]['qty'] = $item->getQty();
        $cart->removeItem($item->getId());
        $cart->setSubtotal(0);
        $cart->setBaseSubtotal(0);
        $cart->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $cart->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $cart->setGrandTotal(0);
        $cart->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

        $cart->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $cart->collectTotals();
    }
    $cart->save();

    foreach ($temparray as $key => $item) {
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
        $quoteObj = $cart;
        $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
        $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productObj = $productModel->load($item['product_id']);
        $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
        $quoteItem->setBasePrice($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setPriceInclTax($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setData('original_price', $productObj->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setData('price', $productObj->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setRowTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
        $quoteItem->setQty($item['qty']);
        $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
        $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
        $quoteObj->setBaseSubtotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setSubtotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setBaseGrandTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());
        $quoteObj->setGrandTotal($productObj->getFinalPrice());

        $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
        $quoteObj->collectTotals();
        $quoteObj->save();
        $this->_quote = $quoteObj;

        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);
        $service->submitAll();
        if ($isNewCustomer) {
            try {
                $this->_involveNewCustomer();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteObj->getId())
                ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteObj->getId())
                ->clearHelperData();
        $order = $service->getOrder();
        if ($order) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after', array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $quoteObj));
            $quoteObj->removeAllItems();
            $quoteObj->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $quoteObj->collectTotals();
        }
        /**
         * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
         * eg: paypal standard ipn
         */
        $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
        /**
         * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
         */
        if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
            try {
                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        // add order information to the session
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
                ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
                ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
        // as well a billing agreement can be created
        $agreement = $order->getPayment()->getBillingAgreement();
        if ($agreement) {
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastBillingAgreementId($agreement->getId());
        }
    }
    // add recurring profiles information to the session
    $profiles = $service->getRecurringPaymentProfiles();
    if ($profiles) {
        $ids = array();
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $ids[] = $profile->getId();
        }
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastRecurringProfileIds($ids);
        // TODO: send recurring profile emails
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'checkout_submit_all_after', array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'recurring_profiles' => $profiles)
    );
    return $this;
}
}
```